# Insertion transaction- rollback SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, many-to-many, rollback

I am new to databases and i try to create a stored procedure that inserts data in tables that are in a many to many relation.If any part of the operation fails then it must try to recover as much as possible from the entire operation. For example, if one wants to create a record regarding publishers and books and succeeds creating the publisher but fails with the book, then it should roll back
the creation of the book, but not of the publisher.

My code looks like this:

```
 BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
      DECLARE @serviciuKey int
      DECLARE @specializareKey int


      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT denumire, moneda, pret FROM Serviciu where denumire=@denumire and moneda=@moneda and pret=@pret)
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Serviciu ( denumire, moneda, pret)
        VALUES (@denumire, @moneda, @pret)
      END
      SET @serviciuKey=@@IDENTITY
      SAVE TRANSACTION savepoint

      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT denumire, descriere FROM Specializare where denumire=@denumire_spec AND descriere=@descriere)
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Specializare( denumire, descriere)
        VALUES (@denumire_spec, @descriere)
      END
      SET @specializareKey=@@IDENTITY
      SAVE TRANSACTION savepoint

      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Specializare_Serviciu where cod_specializare=@specializareKey and cod_serviciu=@serviciuKey)
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Specializare_Serviciu( cod_specializare, cod_serviciu)
        VALUES (@specializareKey, @serviciuKey)
      END
      SAVE TRANSACTION savepoint
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION savepoint
      DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048) = error_message()  
      RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1)
      RETURN 55555
   END CATCH
```

When i execute the procedure, i have this error:
Msg 3931, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AddData0, Line 76
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.

Also when i try to insert some data that already exists, it is inserted with another ID, which means that IF NOT EXIST statement is not working.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
DECLARE @serviciuKey int
DECLARE @specializareKey int

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT denumire, moneda, pret FROM Serviciu where denumire=@denumire and moneda=@moneda and pret=@pret)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Serviciu ( denumire, moneda, pret)
        VALUES (@denumire, @moneda, @pret)
    END

    SET @serviciuKey=scope_identity()

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT denumire, descriere FROM Specializare where denumire=@denumire_spec AND descriere=@descriere)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Specializare( denumire, descriere)
        VALUES (@denumire_spec, @descriere)
    END

    SET @specializareKey=scope_identity()

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Specializare_Serviciu where cod_specializare=@specializareKey and cod_serviciu=@serviciuKey)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Specializare_Serviciu( cod_specializare, cod_serviciu)
        VALUES (@specializareKey, @serviciuKey)
    END

    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@trancount > 0 
        ROLLBACK TRAN

    DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048) = error_message()  
    RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1)
    RETURN 55555
END CATCH
```